# Browser Notification basic simple code not working in Firefox, Edge, but works in Chrome

Tags: push-notification, web-push

I have this code, that can be tested in any developer console (Firefox, Chrome, Edge).
Expectations are:

- first, click ask for permissions
- second click display notification message

  ```
  document.onclick=function() {
    let permission = Notification.permission;

    if(permission === "granted"){
       showNotification();
    } else if(permission === "default"){
       requestAndShowPermission();
    } else {
      alert("Use normal alert");
    }

    function requestAndShowPermission() {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            if (permission === "granted") {
                showNotification();
            }
        });
    }
    function showNotification() {
      //  if(document.visibilityState === "visible") {
      //      return;
      //  }
       let title = "Testing webpush";
       let icon = 'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/zelda.png';
       let body = "Message to be displayed";

       let notification = new Notification(title, { body });

       notification.onclick = () => {
              notification.close();
              window.parent.focus();
       }

    }
   }
  ```

It's just displaying a basic notification. It works well when clicking anything on a Chrome page, but nothing happens with Firefox and Edge.

I have no custom settings for the browsers. Please what do I seem to be doing wrong?

Comment: just to let this here for others having the problem. OS did stop the notifications for the app. So both Firefox and Edge had the notification option disabled at the app level.